# Previously I rendered the image from google drive now I need to render it from local path. How can I render images in const variable in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css

```
 render() {
    const file1 = {
      "name": "xxxxx",
       "img" : "https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1zeBeWS26cF" 
 //**"previously I calling the image from google drive now I need to 
         render it from local path. how can I do that?"**,
        "details" : "blah blah"
};
         const file2 = {
      "name": "xxxxx",
       "img" : "https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1zeBeWS26cFxxxxxx"    
//**"previously I calling the image from google drive now I need to 
         render it from local path. how can I do that?"**,
        "details" : "blah blah"
};

  return (
      <div className="bio_mainDiv">
        <div className="cards"><BioCard card={file1}/></div> **//So I am not able use <img src="" /> here..**
        <div className="cards"><BioCard card={file2}/></div>
</div>
);
}
```

**BioCard Component**

```
class BioCard extends Component {

  handleDetailClick = () => {
    this.props.showDetails(this.props.card);
  };

  render() {
    const currcard = this.props.card;
    const name = currcard.name;
    const details = currcard.desc;
    const img = currcard.img;

    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleDetailClick}>
        <div className="biocard_main">
          <img className="biocard_img" src={img} alt=""/>
          <div className="biocard_name">{name}</div>
          <div className="biocard_details">{details}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

BioCard.propTypes = {
  card: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(BioCard);
```

Previously I rendered the image from google drive it worked fine. Now I need to render it from local path. How can I render images in const variable in Reactjs? I can't use img tag here, what are my options here.

Answer (score 1):

Importing modules using require or importing modules using es6

The import statement is used to import bindings which are exported by another module. Imported modules are in strict mode whether you declare them as such or not. The import statement cannot be used in embedded scripts.

```
1. Using Import

import imgPath from '../img' //local path of image in application

render() {
    const file1 = {
        "name": "xxxxx",
        "img": "https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1zeBeWS26cF",
             //**"previously I calling the image from google drive now I need to render it from local path.how can I do that ? "**,
        "details": "blah blah"
    };
    const file2 = {
        "name": "xxxxx",
        "img": imgPath,
        //**"previously I calling the image from google drive now I need to render it from local path.how can I do that ? "**,
        "details": "blah blah"
    };

    return (
        <div className="bio_mainDiv">
            <div className="cards"><BioCard card={file1} /></div> **//So I am not able use <img src="" /> here..**
            <div className="cards"><BioCard card={file2} /></div>
        </div>
    );
}

2. Using require

render() {
    const file1 = {
        "name": "xxxxx",
        "img": "https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1zeBeWS26cF",
        //**"previously I calling the image from google drive now I need to render it from local path.how can I do that ? "**,
        "details": "blah blah"
    };
    const file2 = {
        "name": "xxxxx",
        "img": require('.../img'),
        //**"previously I calling the image from google drive now I need to render it from local path.how can I do that ? "**,
        "details": "blah blah"
    };

    return (
        <div className="bio_mainDiv">
            <div className="cards"><BioCard card={file1} /></div> **//So I am not able use <img src="" /> here..**
            <div className="cards"><BioCard card={file2} /></div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried both but did't work. Can you give me example how to render the img? thanks for help

Comment: Can you post your BioCard component in which are you sending this json

Comment: added the BioCard source above.

Comment: Thanks I corrected my mistake, using require to call my img.